# What is the largest possible order of a permutation in $S_{n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I was trying to solve the following question (from this [link](https://maths.ucd.ie/modules/math30300/homework5-10-sols.pdf)):

> What is the largest possible order of a permutation in $S_{10}$?

I though there is some sophisticated way to solve it but then I read the solution (also located in the link). Is there a better, more sophisticated way to solve such problems for $S_n$, then writing down all the elements and their orders?

For example, finding the largest possible order of a permutation in $S_{101}$  will be much harder.

Comment: I think it will be $30.$

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Hi, thanks for the reply. You are correct but how to calculate without writing down all the elements?

Comment: Can you find an element of order $30$ in $S_{10}$?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000793

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Yes. But the question is how to find the largest order in $S_n$ (like $S_100$) without writing down all the ways to calculate $lcm$.